# How to insert multiple textfield data of a form into selected columns of a database table in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a jinternal frame form with textfields. I am entering name and no to these textfields. I need to insert these data into my database table addstudents. In addstudent table there are more columns not only no and name column.
So I need to type select query inserting textfield data into selected columns.

```
String n = no.getText();
String nm = name.getText();

  select no,name from addstudent insert into...
```

i can't find how to insert data to selected columns of the db table..
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use a SQL `INSERT` statement, and use a Java `PreparedStatement`:

```
String n = no.getText();
String nm = name.getText();

String sql = "INSERT INTO addstudent ( no, name )" +
            " VALUES ( ?, ? )";

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, n);
    stmt.setString(2, nm);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```